# uploading files from iOS to web service

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an app on the roll that requires me to upload files from it to a webservice. I am basically a noob in file transfer and in app-webservice comunications and would appreciate a direction in which to go.

The first question is how to encode the file? The webservice has to interpret the data sent so in which way do i do it? I don't own the webservice so i don't know how they pick up files, but i assume in a XML/JSON format.

The second question is how am i to send it? Having a XML object, how do i send it to, let's say, "http://www.website.com/path/to/upload". Is Async available?

If i'm missing or am wrong about a step (or 10) please correct me! Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1: If it is a XML you will need to parse it, and create objet from it. If it's a Json, i recommend you https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit JSONKIt, which is really awesome.

2: You 'll need get that data from webService and ASIHTTP is a really great tool to get fast web service call. The doc is really clear and comprehensible http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ is a must have.

3: You send your data either by url (get) or post.

Hope for you it's not into XML format, this is really painful, believe me